# How to an encrypt a password with sha1 in php

Tags: php, session, encryption, input

I am trying to learn password encryption in `PHP` but not quite getting it.
So I am trying to use/implement `sha1` encryption in my login form.

As you can see in this code, I used `sha1` right next to my if/else condition and just getting an error.

```
<?php

$accountName = "accountuser";
$accountPass = "accountpass";

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['accountName'])) {
  echo "<h1>Welcome " .$_SESSION['accountName']."</h1>";

  header("Refresh: 3; url=index.php");
  include 'login.html';
  echo 'Logged in successfuly! <br> Logging in...';
}
  else {
    if($_POST['username']==$accountName && sha1$_POST['password']==$accountPass){

      $_SESSION['$accountName']=$accountName;

      header("Refresh: 3; url=index.php");

      echo 'Logged in successfuly! <br> Logging in...';
    }

    else {

      include 'login.html';

      echo "Wrong username!";

    }

  }

?>
```

Comment: *"just getting an error."* - Being what?

Comment: Don't roll your own: [`password_hash`](http://php.net/password_hash) / [`password_verify`](http://php.net/password_verify)

Comment: `sha1$_POST['password']` isn't a function call, but a syntax error. Again, see the manual for better examples.

Comment: You put in the text 'sha1', I don't see you actually using the function.  As mario stated, you should not attempt your own hashing (not encryption) solution.  sha1 is outdated, PHP has secure functionality built in.

Comment: Not really an error but its not being encrypted.

Comment: `$_SESSION['$accountName']` another typo.

Comment: Correct the typos then update your post so we know if there is something we can help you with.

Answer (score 1):

Password hashing? **There's a function for that.**

While you **can** use functions like `sha1()`, `md5()` and others to encrypt passwords, it's not the best practise and generally not recommended.

You should use the built-in functions in PHP for this:

- `password_hash()`
- `password_verify()`

You need to use them like so:

```
$password = $_POST['password'];
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Then store `$hash` in your database.

---

To verify whether a password is correct or not, use `password_verify()`, like so:

```
// $hash = stored hash in your database for the user
$password = $_POST['password']; // password put in by user attempting to login

password_verify($password, $hash);
```

`password_verify()` will either return `TRUE` or `FALSE` based on whether the password is correct or not. To check, you can just do this:

`if(!password_verify($password, $hash)) { //password incorrect }`